# How to skip rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know MySQL has LIMIT clause, which has the following two usages:

1. LIMIT k: meaning result[: k]
2. LIMIT m, n: meaning result[m: m + n]

However, what if I want result[k: ]? That is, I want to skip the first k rows, and get all the rests. Is it supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just put in a really big value for the limit.  Something like this usually works:

```
limit k, 999999999
```

Comment: The biggest supported value by LIMIT clause is `18446744073709551615` (maximum value of unsigned BIGINT).

Answer (score 4):

Check the keyword OFFSET :

```
 SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET k
```

see here for more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html